# Tool for querying databases

Tags: database

I want to query a number of different databases mainly Oracle and Informix.
Can anyone suggest me some tool using which I can do this easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try WinSQL lite at http://www.indus-soft.com/SynametricsWebApp/WinSQL.jsp. It is absolutely free and does not expire. It is only one file and does not come with any bulky DLLs. If you don't like it, simply delete the file from your hard drive.

An introduction about how to use it against an informix database can be found in [this article](http://www.inquiry.com/techtips/info_pro/10min/10min0700/10min0700.asp).

Comment: @Daniel Yes it is. See their price list. WinSQL Lite has allways been free: http://www.indus-soft.com/SynametricsWebApp/WinSQLCost.jsp

Comment: Aha, I see it now.  Buried somewhat.

Answer (score 4):

I use and love [DbVisualizer](http://www.minq.se/products/dbvis/).

Answer (score 2):

I like [SQuirreL SQL Client](http://www.squirrelsql.org/). It's cross platform and database independent, and quite handy.

Answer (score 1):

As a previous answer stated, WinSQL is one of the best "generic" sql query programs, although it is far from perfect. Generally speaking, the programs dedicated to a particular sql product are better (usually 3rd party products, not written by the SQL vendor). TOAD is a great program for Oracle (originally written by an Oracle employee in his spare time before being bought by Quest). TOAD has become a little bloated of recent versions, but is still a fantastic product. I think there are versions of TOAD for MySQL and maybe one or two others, however, the Oracle version is by far the best. When I last used Informix (2004) there was a reasonable 3rd party Java program whose name escapes me for the moment. The standard tools that come with Informix are from the dark ages (I used the Unix utilities that look a bit like DOS versions of Lotus 123), so anything else is better. I used WinSQL with Informix with great success.

Answer (score 0):

The best alround one is [TOAD](http://www.toadsoft.com/)

Answer (score 0):

@littlegeek: Toad is not available for Informix.  Additionally, the OP seems to want a single program that can query several different brands of DBMS, and you have to buy a different version of Toad for every DBMS you want to use it with.

Answer (score 0):

Informix is not very well supported among third party database tool vendors.

Interestingly, Oracle' SQL Developer supports browsing (and converting to oracle) several databases, including SQL Server and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- [Query Express](http://www.albahari.com/queryexpress.html) (single 100KB executable, no install)
- [Query ExPlus](http://sourceforge.net/projects/queryexplus/) (improved Query Express)

Answer (score 0):

There is several options on this page: http://freewarehome.com/index.html?http%3A//freewarehome.com/bx/index.php%3Faction%3Dvthread%26forum%3D8%26topic%3D7136

GenDAT is not bad, but I am biased as I did write it !  It has been voted highly though.

I need cross platform now so I use Oracle SQL Developer which I think is great.  It can handle other databases not just Oracle.  Another good one (cross platform) is DB Solo.

Answer (score 0):

I like Aqua Data Studio from [Aquafold](http://aquafold.com/). It supports all of the major database players as well as some of the less including Informix. Great features like code beautification and syntax highlighting are perks.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Aqua Data](http://www.aquafold.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I have used Query Tool for years http://www.gpoulose.com/
It is lightwight and gets the job done.
However, I will also investigate some of the other ones listed here.  Must say that SQLDeveloper and Toad are too bloated for my needs.  I work on many different systems in any day, all at different clients with different security and down to very low-end machines.  Having one simple tool and good SQL chops goes a long way!

I also would like to note that because I am installing it on new servers constantly, it needs to be free, or have an unlimited machine license.  I'd be happy to pay for my own use of the tool, but need to be able to install it over and over again.